# How do I select a table row and grab data from it in razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am new to coding, so sorry in advanced if this is simple.

I have a table that is populated through a foreach loop, iterating through a list of my model's type, which contains all of my properties. This is how my table body looks:

```
<tbody>
@foreach (var row in Model.myModel)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@row.Year</td>
        <td>@row.ID</td>
        <td>@row.User</td>
     </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

There is a way that I want to do this but I am not sure how. I want to be able to click on the row and return the index number, so then I can just get the value straight from the list directly from the list. Is there a way to do this? Or should I be going about this another way?

I am working on a asp.net core web application btw. This is in my Index.cshtml file and so far I only have some code in my Index.cshtml.cs file to get the data from sql server into the list I am using to fill this table.

Comment: Did you consider using javascript or jquery for this?

Comment: Did you mean that you would like to get the index value without looping through the list? Could you please explain clearly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @SRK45 Is using JS in razor pages something I can do? I thought the point of razor pages was to use c# to handle everything in your controllers/ cshtml files. I've never worked with this type of stuff before so I'm not sure.

Comment: @Md Farid Uddin Kiron, I want to be able to click on the table and retrieve the index of the row in the table. I want to do that so I can pull all of the data out from the list that populated it. What I'm considering now is to put a numerical sequence(row number) as another column and just return thag value on click. After that I gotta figure out how methods work in razor pages lol

Comment: Better would be made the row `editable` if users wants to update order value , they would click on `update button` and input their `order quantity` then with that latest value need to be updated in database.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var row in myModel)
    {
        <tr @onclick="@(() => Edit(@row.ID))">
            <td>@row.Year</td>
            <td>@row.ID</td>
            <td>@row.User</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

and add this below:

```
@code {
  private List<Model> myModel = new List<Model>();

  private void Edit(int ID)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("You clicked" + ID);
  }
}
```